# Mockito... Spring testing

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, springmockito

here is my test class..

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
   public Testclass {
     @Autowired
     private VClasss vclass;
       .....
       .....

     @Before
     public void setup() {
       //mockito.when.(vClass.isvalid()).thenReturn(true);

    }
    @After
    public void verify( {
     Mockito.verify(vCLass, VerificationModeFactory.times(1)).isValid();
     Mockito.reset();
    }


   @Test
   public void test1() {
     //set up test which will call the mock isValid method

   }

   @Test
   public void test1() {
    //set up test which will call the mock isValid method
   }


   @Configuration
   static class configurationForTest {
    @Bean
     public VClass vClass() {
      return mockito.mock(VClass.class);
     }
   }
```

My question is that when i set this up, first test passes, as the verify is correct isValid was called once, however the second fails as now verify complains asking that isValid was called twice.. I expected the reset method on mockito to reset the call count afetr each test..

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass any mock to reset. The line should be

```
Mockito.reset(vClass);
```

Comment: Is it possible to reset count for individual method? With line you provided whole mock is resetted.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Resetting a mock is a smell already. Resetting individual methods would be more smelly.